# Colocar datos en un ListBox en ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Como dice el titulo, mi problema es el siguiente:
No puedo cargar los datos de una DB en MSSQL en un LISTBOX en ASP.NET

Mi código cs es el siguiente:

```
namespace User_Login_CS
{
    public partial class usuariossistemas : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        public DataTable CargarData() //Ordena los nombres en una listBox
        {
            string str = "Data Source=IP; Initial Catalog=DB; Persist Security Info=True; user id=id; password=pass;";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
            {
                string com = "SELECT * FROM  [dbo].[UsuariosSistema] ORDER BY Nombre ";
                SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);
                DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
                adpt.Fill(myDataSet, "UsuariosSistemas");
                DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
                return myDataTable;
            }

        }

        public DataTable CargarDatas()//Ordena las empresas en un ListBox
        {
            string str = "Data Source=IP; Initial Catalog=db; Persist Security Info=True; user id=id; password=pass;";
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            string textboxValue = TextBox5.Text;
            string com = "SELECT dbo.Empresas.EmpresaID, dbo.Empresas.Empresa, dbo.UsuariosSistemaEmpresas.UsuariosSistemaID "+
                "FROM dbo.UsuariosSistemaEmpresas "+
                "INNER JOIN dbo.Empresas "+
                "ON dbo.UsuariosSistemaEmpresas.EmpresaID = dbo.Empresas.EmpresaID "+
                "WHERE dbo.UsuariosSistemaEmpresas.UsuariosSistemaID = '"+ textboxValue + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);
            DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
            adpt.Fill(myDataSet, "UsuariosSistema");
            DataTable myDataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
            return myDataTable;

        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)//Carga la data al actualizar la pagina
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DataTable dt = CargarData();
                foreach (DataRow fila in dt.Rows)
                {
                    ListBox1.Items.Add(fila[1] + "");
                }
            }

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                DataTable rt = CargarDatas();
                foreach (DataRow filas in rt.Rows)
                {
                   ListBox2.Items.Add(filas[1] + "");
                }
            }

        }

        protected void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)//Al clickear en un boton, se cargan los datos de la db
        {
            DataTable tabla = CargarData();
            int indice = ListBox1.SelectedIndex;
            TextBox5.Text = Convert.ToString(tabla.Rows[indice][0]);
            TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(tabla.Rows[indice][1]);
            TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(tabla.Rows[indice][2]);
            TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(tabla.Rows[indice][3]);
            TextBox4.Text = Convert.ToString(tabla.Rows[indice][5]);
            CheckBox1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(tabla.Rows[indice][4]);
            CheckBox2.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(tabla.Rows[indice][7]);
            CheckBox3.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(tabla.Rows[indice][8]);
        }



    }
}
```

Mi codigo de ASPX es

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="usuariossistemas.aspx.cs" Inherits="User_Login_CS.usuariossistemas" %>

<h1>Lista de nombres</h1>
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" class="form-control listadenombres" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:ListBox>

                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Mostrar Información" class="btn btn-primary botoninfo"/>

<h1>Datos</h1>
<asp:TextBox class="form-control nombresyapellidos" ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:TextBox class="form-control nombresyapellidos" ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox class="form-control nombresyapellidos" ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox class="form-control nombresyapellidos" ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox class="form-control nombresyapellidos" ID="TextBox5" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<h1>Listado de empresas</h1>
<asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

La lista de nombres si funciona, pero para cargar la lista de empresas, no me esta dando resultado.
Carga hasta un punto, si lo pruebo desde mi local, pero si lo subo en red, es peor, no sé si sea por ello.
Estuve viendo otros codigos desde forums.asp.net pero no encuentro respuesta, al igual que aquí, espero que puedan ayudarme.
Se los agradezco de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes un `DataTable` no necesitas iterar para asignar los `Items.Add()` puedes usar directo el `DataSource` algo como esto

```
DataTable rt = CargarDatas();

ListBox2.DataSource = rt;
ListBox2.DataTextField = "EmpresaID";
ListBox2.DataValueField = "Empresa";
ListBox2.DataBind();
```

Ademas tu codigo podria mejorarse

```
private string str = "Data Source=IP; Initial Catalog=DB; Persist Security Info=True; user id=id; password=pass;";

public DataTable CargarData()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        string com = "SELECT * FROM  [dbo].[UsuariosSistema] ORDER BY Nombre ";
        SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(com, con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adpt.Fill(dt);

        return dt;
    }

}
```

Y ademas debes usar parametros

```
public DataTable CargarDatas()
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str))
    {
        string com = @"SELECT E.EmpresaID, 
                            E.Empresa, 
                            U.UsuariosSistemaID
                    FROM dbo.UsuariosSistemaEmpresas U
                    INNER JOIN dbo.Empresas E
                    ON U.EmpresaID = E.EmpresaID
                    WHERE U.UsuariosSistemaID = @id";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(com, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text));

        SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adpt.Fill(dt);

        return dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Me indica: "System.FormatException: 'La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.'" -   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(TextBox5.Text));

Comment: validaste que en el textbox hayas ingresado un numero valido ? si lo dejas vacio va a fallar

Comment: En el "ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged" al momento de darle click al boton "Mostrar informacion", los campos se rellenan, incluido el campo de texto que indico en el problema.

Comment: si el error es que la cadena que tiene el TextBox5 no esta en el formato correcto quiere decir que no es numero valido que se pueda convertir para usar en el parametro, puedes poner un breakpoint he inspeccionar que valor esta tomando el .Text de ese textbox5